# Outlook deferredDeliveryTime goes to outbox and If application is closed it does not send

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin, office-addins, mapi

I am building an Outlook Add-in that is using the Outlook mailitem property deferredDeliveryTime in order to postpone the sending of the message. Everything works fine but I have realized that if I send an email using deferedDeliveryTime and the application is closed it won't send the email until the application is reopened which defeats the purpose of the add-in. I am using Exchange/Office 365 and should therefore be able to push the message to the messaging queue and then close the application but I don't know how to do this.

One solution I have found is disabling the "Use Cached Exchange Mode to download email to an Outlook data file" in Account Settings. When disabled it sends the message immediately to the Exchange server but I need this setting to be enabled due to group policy.

I believe it should be possible to have it enabled while still being able to immediately send to Exchange. Do anyone know how/if this works? Or if there is some workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right avenue, Outlook add-ins work only when the host application is launched. When you deal with a cached mode of connecting to the Exchange server your data is kept locally until Outlook synchronizes its folders. The non-cached mode works a bit different - the data is reflected from the server-side and no cache is preserved locally, your changes are reflected on the server-side almost immediately. It seems you have found a possible workaround already.

But you may also consider using EWS when Outlook is closed at any point of time, see [Explore the EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/explore-the-ews-managed-api-ews-and-web-services-in-exchange) for more information. For Office365 accounts you may take a look at MS Graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried that particular scenario, but you should be able to create a message in the online mode and send it in that mode. On the Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) level, you can open the parent folder (e.g., Outbox) with the `MAPI_NO_CACHE` flag, create the message (`IMAPIFolder::CreateMessage`), populate its properties, and send it (`IMessage::SubmitMesage`) - since the parent folder is opened in the online mode, the newly created message will also be in the online mode.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can try to use [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author, any language) - it will let you open a folder in the online mode ([RDOSession](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm)`.GetFolderFromID(..., MAPI_NO_CACHE | MAPI_BEST_ACCESS)`).